# How do I use logfile created in Conftest.py in other files?

Tags: python, logging

I have following setup

```
../test/dirA
../test/Conftest.py
../test/Test_1.py
../test/logging.config
```

Code for Conftest.py

```
import logging.config
from os import path
import time
config_file_path = path.join(path.dirname(path.abspath(__file__)), 'logging.conf')
log_file_path = path.join(path.dirname(path.abspath(__file__)), ‘logFile.log’)
logging.config.fileConfig(config_file_path)

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

fh = logging.FileHandler(log_file_path)
fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setLevel(logging.ERROR)

# add the handlers to the logger
logger.addHandler(fh)
logger.addHandler(ch)

logging.info('done')
```

Code for ../test/Test_1.py

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def test_foo():
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.info("testing foo")

def test_foobar():
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.info("testing foobar")
```

I need to see logs from both files in logFile.log but currently I see only log from conftest.py. What am I missing?

Also, I noticed that if I execute Conftest.py from test folder (one dir up), for some reason it does not see logging.config.

Is my usage for conftest for correct for logging?
How else I can achieve same result?

Thank you

**Update:** 
I used approach described

1. https://blog.muya.co.ke/configuring-multiple-loggers-python/.
2. https://fangpenlin.com/posts/2012/08/26/good-logging-practice-in-python/

With some changes, this addresses my question.
Another lesson I learned that use

```
 logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

at function level, not at module level.
*You can see a lots of example out there (including this article, I did it just for giving example in short) get logger at module level. They looks harmless, but actually, there is a pitfall – Python logging module respects all created logger before you load the configuration from a file, if you get logger at the module level like this*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used approach described at https://blog.muya.co.ke/configuring-multiple-loggers-python/.

With some changes, this addresses my question.

Answer (score 0):

Well, my first guess is that if you don't import the Conftest.py in the test_1.py, the logger setup code is not reached and executed, so the logging in the Test_1 file is in a default location log file.

Try this line to find the location of the log file:

```
logging.getLoggerClass().root.handlers[0].baseFilename
```

Comment: I am not clear how to use code you wrote above. Please elaborate. Sorry if I do not see obvious.

Comment: Well, this snippet should return a string, so you can add it at the end of your script, all scripts, or in the console log after you executed the script/s. Just try it, it won't break anything